# Regex to extract part of URL that can be in the middle or end

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

So I have a URL that could be in the following three formats:

```
https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/edit
https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/
https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234
```

I would like to extract only the `abcd-1234` bit from the above URLs. I've tried doing so using the following regular expression, however it will only capture the first and second case.

```py
import re

id = re.search(r'https://www.example.com/d/(.+?)/', url).group(1)
```

For `url=https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234` the above will fail with:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

given that it does not match the regex.

What regex shall I use in order to indicate that the part of interest could be followed by no character at all?

Comment: Given that you know it always start with `https://www.example.com/d/` (based on regex pattern) and you want just the next element of the url, why the regex, just split at `/` and take element with index 4

Comment: This should work too: `re.search(r'https://www.example.com/d/([-\w]+)', url).group(1)`

Comment: @swift should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Questor, it's not much, and not better than Michael Cao's answer, so not really worthy of an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for forward slash or end of string with `$`:

```
re.search(r"https://www.example.com/d/(.+?)(?:/|$)", url).group(1)
```

Comment: Never use `(.+?)(?:/|$)`. Use `[^/]*` / `[^/]+`. Better performance and cross-platform support. Always check for a match before accessing the group value, or you risk getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp fails to match the 3rd example URL because of trailing `/` in your pattern (which is not present in that URL, so no match). So you need to correct your regexp to account for that too:

```
r'https://www.example.com/d/(.+?)(?:/|$)'
```

It looks almost like yours, yet the last non-capturing group `(?:/|$)`, that have two alternatives to match: either `/` character or (`|`) end of your string (`$`).

```py
import re

urls = [
    'https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/edit',
    'https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/',
    'https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234',
]

for url in urls:
    id = re.search(r'https://www.example.com/d/(.+?)(?:/|$)', url).group(1)
    print(f'{id} <- {url}')
```

produces expected

```
abcd-1234 <- https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/edit
abcd-1234 <- https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/
abcd-1234 <- https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234
```

Alternatively, if URL structure is fixed, you can split the string by `/` and get the 4th element:

```bash
$ "https://www.example.com/d/abcd-1234/edit".split('/')
 0         1   2                  3    4
['https:', '', 'www.example.com', 'd', 'abcd-1234', 'edit']
```

Answer (score 0):

### First

Have you heard of regex101.com? I highly recommend using it.

### Second.

Let's talk about your regex.

`(.+?)/`:

- `(...)` Creates a capture group
- `.+` Match one or more characters
- `.+?` Match one or more characters as few times as possible (lazy capture).
- `/` Match the forward slash (/)..

As it stands right now your regex will look for a one to infinite string that ends in a forward slash.

Change your capture group `(.+?)/` to capture your abcdef-1234...
`([^/]+)`:

- `(...)` Creates a capture group
- `[^/]+` Capture one or more characters that are not forward slashes.